# VoIP with Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hello there
I would like to know if it is possible to have voip with flash.
If so how can I do this (tutorial maybe)
Basically what I want to do is on my website have a box where i can type in lets say someones ip address and start a connection  with them.

I have a Linux godaddy server will this be a problem?
thanks in advance.

For example:
https://www.gizmocall.com/gc/app?class=GizmoCall&proc=gcStart

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318275/flash-player-and-voip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash doesn't support VOIP itself.  AFAIK it can only talk to Flash Media Server endpoints for audio publishing/streaming.

There are FMS implementations available that may allow you to bridge to a VOIP server though.  I think [Red5](http://www.osflash.org/red5) may do that, or have plugins that allow it.  I believe there are also some commercial applications that will do it as well.  But Flash player doesn't have anything built in to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What aboout Ribbit?
http://docs.ribbit.com/ribbit-flash-toolkit